# How to treat missing values as null

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, interpolation, missing-data

I have an excel file with missing values encoded as blanks and I want this excel file to be converted into DBF but with the conversion process, the blanks (missing values) become 0.

The reason I am doing this is because I want to perform interpolation but because of the missing values becoming 0 the interpolation becomes wrong.

My question is how to treat missing values as  without deleting the point shapefile and still proceed with interpolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you export your Excel sheet to a geodatabase table, the blank values will remain blank, they won't be converted to 0.

One of the ways you can do this is by right-clicking the Excel sheet in the Catalog > Export > To Geodatabase (single)...

[image]

Comment: how do I do that? my apologies for inconveniences.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do that but it seems that blank values became 0.

Comment: Hi, What I did is not to save the file in a folder but inside a GDB and export it as GDB (Single). Thank you thank you.